# What is the sum of number of digits of the numbers $2^{2001}$ and $5^{2001}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving, decimal-expansion

What is the sum of number of digits of the numbers $2^{2001}$ and $5^{2001}$? (Singapore 1970)

I attempted to solve this question by working out what each digit must be, and maybe find some pattern, but I couldn't find any, apart from the fact that $2^{2001}\mod{10}\equiv 4$ and $2^{2001}\pmod{10}\equiv 5$. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question? This question is multiple choice with options $1999, 2003, 4002, 6003, 2002$

Comment: @samerivertwice yes base 10

Comment: Not hard to do with a computer program, but perhaps that's not allowed.

Comment: @Sil I am certain that that is what the question asks

Comment: @Sil sorry for not having written that in the question originally, it normally doesn't play a role, I'll edit the question now

Comment: @Sil I'll ask the author for an explanation, as soon as I get a response, I'll post it here

Comment: @sil I worked it out given the multi choice 

Comment: @lonestudent the reason I accepted that answer, is mainly because of hgmath comment, which shows how to calculate the log

Comment: @Sil there seems to be no problem with the question.

Comment: @lonestudent the question initially wasn't complete that's why :)

Comment: But it's true the comments are no longer relevant so im gonna remove them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's $2002$.  It's asking for the sum of the **number of digits** of $2^{2001}$ and $5^{2001}$ in base $10$, so just take the log base $10$ of each, take the ceiling function and hey presto:

$603+1399=2002$

Comment: remark: *without* taking the ceiling function, $$2001\log_{10}(2)+2001\log_{10}(5) = 2001(\log_{10}(2)+\log_{10}(5)) = 2001\log_{10}(10) = 2001$$ so no calculator is needed to know the answer is in $[2001,2003)$

Comment: "the sum of the number of digits"  Well, that's just nasty.....

Comment: @hgmath nice. I figured there was something like that although I just used the calculator ;)

Comment: @samerivertwice your solution is brilliant, thank you very much

Comment: @MichaelBlane for the logarithm I just used a calculator.  If needed to do without a calculator this can be done, using an infinite series for the log function but the real magic is in hgmath's comment - if you want to learn something, that comment is the thing to think about.

Comment: @samerivertwice ok great, thank you very much once again, your solution is brilliant

Answer (score 19):

It looks like you don't need logarithms or any calculator to solve this problem. Let's start.

First, observe that the following inequalities hold:

$$10^m<\underbrace {2^{2001}}_{m+1 ~ \text{digits}}<10^{m+1}$$

$$10^n<\underbrace{5^{2001}}_{n+1 ~ \text{digits}}<10^{n+1}$$

You get,

$$10^{m+n}<10^{2001}<10^{m+n+2}$$

$$2001=m+n+1$$

$$m+n=2000$$

Finally,  the sum of digits of $2^{2001}$ and $5^{2001}$ is equal :

$$\begin{align}\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black}{m+1+n+1=m+n+2\\ \qquad \qquad \qquad\thinspace=2000+2 \\\qquad \qquad \qquad \thinspace=2002.}}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

The answer is
$$
\overbrace{\lfloor2001\log_{10}(2)\rfloor+1}^\text{digits in $2^{2001}$}+\overbrace{\lfloor2001\log_{10}(5)\rfloor+1}^\text{digits in $5^{2001}$}
$$
However, we also have, using [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket),
$$
\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor=\lfloor x+y\rfloor-[\{x\}+\{y\}\ge1]
$$
So we need to know $\{2001\log_{10}(2)\}+\{2001\log_{10}(5)\}$, but since $2001\log_{10}(2)+2001\log_{10}(5)=2001$, we know that the sum of their fractional parts is exactly $0$ or exactly $1$. Since the fractional parts are both positive, we must have exactly $1$.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lfloor2001\log_{10}(2)\rfloor+1+\lfloor2001\log_{10}(5)\rfloor+1
&=\lfloor2001\log_{10}(2)+2001\log_{10}(5)\rfloor+1\\
&=2002
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I see that I answered the question *after* it was edited to be correct. It was probably that edit which brought this question to the top of the front page just as I was looking.

Answer (score 2):

**Generalization of the problem:**

- What is the sum of number of digits of the numbers $2^N$ and $5^N$?

$$10^m<\underbrace {2^{N}}_{m+1 ~ \text{digits}}<10^{m+1}$$

$$10^n<\underbrace{5^{N}}_{n+1 ~ \text{digits}}<10^{n+1}$$

$$10^{m+n}<10^{N}<10^{m+n+2}$$

$$N= m+n+1$$

$$ m+n=N-1$$

The sum of digits of the numbers $2^{N}$ and $5^{N}$ will be equal :

$$\begin{align}\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black}{m+1+n+1=m+n+2\\ \qquad \qquad \qquad\thinspace=N-1+2 \\\qquad \qquad \qquad \thinspace=N+1.}}}\end{align}$$

- Short answer: $N+1$ digits.